# Adding another port to listen in httpd.conf crashes Apache

Tags: apache, centos7

The requirement of the project is when someone access the application using port `80`, they should see the default application however if someone access the application with port `8083` then they should see the control panel of the application.

I'm on CentOS, adding `Listen 80` and `Listen 8083` in `httpd.conf` crashes Apache.

***cpanel.conf***

```
<VirtualHost *:8083>
        ServerName cpanel.com
        ServerAlias www.cpanel.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/cpanel
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart Apache, I get the following error messsage.

***Error Message***

```
 httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-07-07 18:56:00 EDT; 7min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 14972 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 14971 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14971 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain httpd[14971]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: co...083
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain httpd[14971]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: co...083
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain httpd[14971]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain httpd[14971]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited...URE
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain kill[14972]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exi...s=1
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 07 18:56:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I'm very new to this so your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could first verify that there is nothing already listening to port 8083 prior to start Apache, by example with :

```
netstat -an|grep LISTEN|grep 8083
```

Also, are you starting Apache under root ? You need to if you want it to listen to port 80. What's bugging me it's the log entry stating that it can't open the log. Did you change anything else beside adding Listen 8083 ?